# Loading AmCharts export plugin in VueJS component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, amcharts

I am using a VueJS component that has a structure like this:

Example.vue

```
<template></template>
<script></script>
<style></style>
```

I have pulled in AmCharts 3 via nodejs, and am loading the libraries here:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <div>
            <div id="chartdiv" class="chartStyling" style="width:1000px; height:500px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    require('amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts');
    require('amcharts3/amcharts/serial');
    require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/export');
    require('amcharts3/amcharts/themes/dark');

    module.exports = {
        props: ['chartData', 'chartDetails', 'graphData', 'hiddenParticipants'],
        data: function() {
            return {
                state: {
                    chart: '',
                }
            }
        },
... more code here
```

The chart and various export functions load correctly. However, none of them work; I get the following errors in my console:

[image]

Any ideas on what the issue may be? I imagine this may be due to webpack or the way components are handled.

EDIT: Attempted to include each individual plugin with a require statement as such:

```
require('amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/serial');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/export');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/blob.js/blob');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver');    
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/pdfmake/pdfmake');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/jszip/jszip');    
require('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/xlsx/xlsx');
require('amcharts3/amcharts/themes/dark');
```

Resulting in this error when running npm:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 7 errors                                                      23:45:24

These dependencies were not found:

* fs in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/xlsx/xlsx.js, ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric.js
* jsdom in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric.js
* canvas in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric.js
* xmldom in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save fs jsdom canvas xmldom


These relative modules were not found:

* ./jszip.js in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/xlsx/xlsx.js
* ./dist/cpexcel.js in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/xlsx/xlsx.js
```

Comment: Have you tried to require those files as well? They are under [these folders when looking at the Git repo](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/tree/master/amcharts/plugins/export/libs). Your setup looks very different. I'm wondering whether AmCharts recommendations would help you: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-amcharts-vue-js-webpack/

Comment: I actually have not -- would you require those files individually without requiring export, or doing so in addition to export? I believe export somehow references and requires those files. I also followed that to test things out, but it did nothing

Comment: You can load them with the export plugin. Please check more about that here: https://github.com/amcharts/export#loading-external-libraries-needed-for-operation-of-this-plugin

Comment: Gave that a shot, but got some errors with npm -- posted above